# How to prevent locking of source table when using MERGE?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

It says "NOLOCK and READUNCOMMITTED aren't allowed."

If I cannot use NOLOCK in a MERGE statement, then is there any way to prevent the source table from getting locked?

For example by creating a view that has a select query on source table using NOLOCK. Then I can use this view as source table of MERGE query. Is that a good way to prevent locking of source table when doing MERGE?

Comment: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): What issue do you think you are having that you think `NOLOCK` will solve? It's highly unlikely that `NOLOCK` would have been the right answer, never mind that `NOLOCK` is always ignored anyway in a data modification context.

Comment: If you must use NOLOCK then you can write a merge pattern using standard T-SQL.  'MERGE" is simply a programming construct.  Identical results can be had.  And, from my viewpoint, you would be better off without MERGE. It has too many performance hits for me to use it in a production environment.  Below is just one article on performance issues caused by MERGE. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: SQL server default is read committed. In this mode the source table row will be locked when the merge is running. So I wanted to use nolock

Comment: @jim `MERGE` does have concurrency issues, as well as (mostly now fixed) bugs, as outlined in that article. There is no indication of performance issues if used correctly

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says "NOLOCK and READUNCOMMITTED aren't allowed" for target table not for table source.

Under the default isolation level `READ COMMITTED` SQL Server uses shared locks for reading. Table source is not usually locked entirely. SQL Server usually uses row locks, but they can be escalated to table locks.

Under the `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT` isolation level table source is not locked at all, except schema stability lock.

Updated or inserted rows in target table by MERGE statement are always exclusively locked by SQL Server, and again SQL Server can escalate to table locks.

Comment: Where do I put the NOLOCK in a merge statement in order to prevent any locking on source table? Example: MERGE TARGETTBL A USING SOURCETBL B WITH NOLOCK ON A.ID=B.ID. Is this right.

Comment: Never is right to use NOLOCK. Use READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT isolation level instead, it has all advantages of NOLOCK and none of its drawbacks

Comment: Rowlocks are never escalated to page lock, only to table/partition lock. The engine decides at start whether to begin with row, page or table locks